# SQL selecting item with "begin with"/ putting a % behind a variable's name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to select all rows, where the column g_folder exists in the beginning of the search word.
For example: One element in the table c_groups is '/f1' (in column g_folder). So I want to have only the items, which are in the beginning of the search word:

It should look like: `g_folder% is like '/f1/xx';` 
But I can't put this percent behind a variable. How can I do this?

My statement:

```
   select count(*) from c_groups where g_folder is like '/f1/xx'
```

Comment: Then my answer may need to be adjusted for syntax.  I think mysql uses `||` to concat

Comment: or `CONCAT(g_folder, '%')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, you can concatenate your column like so:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  c_groups
WHERE
  '/f1/xx' LIKE (g_folder + '%')
```

Comment: From my knowledge: Use `CONCAT(g_folder, '%')` for MySQL or Oracle. Use `g_folder || '%'` for Oracle. Use `g_folder + '%'` for SQL Server.